# How to implement timeout with Quartz?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

i'm trying to find the best way to implement a timeout with quartz but i want to know if this framework already contains a class or interface to do it. The timeout that need to implement it's because i want to know how long have been work the job, and take the desicion of turn off the job.

Comment: Try the endTime parameter yet?
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson05.html

Comment: hi, and thanks for asking, i really don't used because i think that parameter it's just for end a job afer certain time. And i wanna know how long the job have doing the operation to avoid a infinite loop

Comment: Ok, so you are looking for a way to track the uptime of the scheduler more then a timeout. Try looking at the documentation for listeners. I have not used them, but they would seem like the logical choice to monitor the state/time of your application running.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the java platform does not provide any way to stop a thread, Quartz does not provide any way to stop a job executing on a thread.

Jobs need to take care of themselves, as Quartz can have no idea what code is in their execute() method.

I'd suggest using System.currentTimeMillis() at the beginning of your job execute() method to record the current time, and then every time through your job's main loop use it again to get the current time.  Look at the difference to see if your maximum time has past,and if so break out of your main loop and exit from the execute() method.

Comment: Also see the InterruptableJob interface.  And the JobListener interface, which give you tools for adding some simple features to the framework that meet your needs.

Comment: But if the job is one shot and without loop, How can I check that you said ?